# What is this solution to a race condition called?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I've seen this pattern used before but I can't recall the terminology used to describe it (and thus I can't Google it to learn more about it):

Basically, it's where you've got a resource that is used by multiple threads, but instead of locking access to that resource, committing a transaction, and then unlocking access, the resource has its own "queue" and each process "posts" a function to be performed on that resource to its queue.  The resource then goes through and executes each function in the order that it was posted, ensuring that its state is never corrupted.

Comment: Sounds like nothing more than asynchronous and delayed execution. Not sure if that pattern has a name. Also not sure if it is related to race conditions per se (as it just synchronizes access to a single resource, but access across multiple resources seems to be unregulated -- and less predictable than with the transaction locking your described before).

Comment: It is a very common pattern, this is how COM apartment threading works.  So, arbitrarily, "apartment threading" is a label.  The underlying data structure is a "producer/consumer queue".  The message queue in the case of COM.

Comment: maybe transactional memory ? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most specific term that can be used here is **Actor**. I think of an actor as a "thread" (or thread-like process) that is...

- ...alive: It can act independently from other actors
- ...has state: It can store data and ensure proper access.

The implementation of such an actor is often a thread that is processing a synchronized queue of messages.

Just calling this "synchronization" is correct but unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

It is called **Synchronization**. From your description it seems you are using mutex locks.

Comment: That seems to apply to both patterns, the one with locking and committing, and the other one with the queueing that he is asking about.

Comment: Huh, okay thanks.  Though.. I thought synchronization was more of a generic term that applied to any strategy for eliminating race conditions (mutex locks would not be a form of synchronizing access?)